# wxpython support for chat like window

Tags: python, wxpython

I have been searching through for a while -how to go about making the gui for chat like window.
The basic need is to show the FB wall post sort of thing (constantly updating). (co-relating it with chat window) where there are multiple post and each post have demarking line.

```
img post 1
------------
img post 2
------------ (along with scrolling enabled.)
```

Have explored some parts of TextCtrl/Combo Box, but would like to take suggestions about existing modules,if any, for something similar or any other good approach with TextCtrl/Combo Box.

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of the text control widgets. The RichText ones or the StyledText controls would allow font manipulations fairly easily. Or you could create a custom widget using something like wx.ClientDC to draw the text and write some scrolling code yourself. The latter is harder, but more flexible.

I think the ideal way to do this would be with wxWebkit, but that project is still in the early stages.